# Remove the smallest value in a list python question

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

The question asks to build a function that will return the list of numbers except the first encountered minimum number in that list. And if an empty list is provided than return an empty list.
For example: [1, 2, 3, 1, 1] -> [2, 3, 1, 1]
My code though is returning [2, 3] only even though the two ones in the back of the list were not encountered before the first one and thus should not be returned.
My code:

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    list1 = []
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return numbers
    for number in numbers[:len(numbers)]:
        if numbers.index(number) != numbers[numbers.index(min(numbers))]:
            list1.append(number)
    return list1
```

Expected: [1, 2, 3, 1, 1] -> [2, 3, 1, 1]
Output: [2, 3]

Comment: list.index() will always return the index of first occurance.

Comment: `numbers.remove(min(numbers))` would remove the first occurrence of min number from `numbers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a copy of the input list then:

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    if numbers is None or len(numbers) == 0:
        return []
    copy = numbers.copy()
    copy.remove(min(numbers))
    return copy

print(remove_smallest([1,0,0,1]))
```

**output:**

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

**Alternative:**

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    if numbers is None or len(numbers) == 0:
        return []
    i = numbers.index(min(numbers))
    return numbers[:i] + numbers[i+1:]
```

Comment: Im pretty sure the only to solve it is with remove but I cant use remove. So removing a different way would be next option. Thank you.

Comment: I just submitted this to the Kata and it is accepted. Why can't you use *remove()*?

Comment: Yes yours worked. The kata simply does not allow for removal of the minimum value that way. Though using the copy function can surpass that test.

Comment: OK - I'l delete this. I have just re-read the Kata instructions and you are completely **wrong**. There is nothing that says that *remove()* can't be used. Using the *copy()* / *remove()* technique (in case you're in the slightest bit interested) is faster than the slicing technique. Sorry to have troubled you. Oops! Seems I can't delete it because some poor misguided fool has accepted it as an Answer. How very strange

Comment: I was mentioning using the remove function on its own and not alongside the copy function.

Answer (score 1):

With the for loop and the if statement, you have filtered all the numbers that are not the minimum number.

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return numbers
    for number in numbers[:len(numbers)]:
        if(number == min(numbers)):
            numbers.remove(number)
            break
    return numbers
```

This would be a better code. There is a break statement to exit the loop when the if condition is satisfied and the pointer goes into the if block.

There can be more efficient ways to solve this too.

Comment: I cannot mutate the list try the code here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/563cf89eb4747c5fb100001b/train/python

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. Use this:

```py
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    smallest = min(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        if number == smallest:
            numbers.remove(number)
    return numbers
```

Hope this is what you needed

Edit: From your problem, I assume there can be multiple smallest numbers. So instead, use this:

```py
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    smallest = min(numbers)
    newList = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number != smallest:
            newList.append(number)
    return newList
```

Edit2: Ok so now I finally understood your problem. Here is the working code:

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    smallestIndex = numbers.index(min(numbers))
    print(smallestIndex)
    numbers.pop(smallestIndex)
    return numbers

print(remove_smallest([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]))
```

Output is: `[2, 3, 1, 1]`
This worked on all the tests

Comment: What he needs is only `numbers.remove(min(numbers))` as @Jay said

Comment: I cannot mutute the orginal list. Here is a link to the question: https://www.codewars.com/kata/563cf89eb4747c5fb100001b/train/python

Comment: @JCaesar it works fine on `[1, 0, 0, 1]` The output is `[1, 1]`

Comment: Yes the issue is that there is more than one of the same minimum number but the first one is the only one that should be used. So to accomplish that we cannot compare each number in the list using values but instead indexes. So as long as the index of the first minumum number is 0 we can compare the rest of the numbers even if they are the same.

Comment: I have edited the answer. It passed all of the tests and I think that is what you were looking for.